# HDFS C Driver Error

Tags: java, hadoop

When I try to use HDFS C Driver, I get this error =>

```
(unable to get stack trace for java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception: ExceptionUtils::getStackTrace error.)
```

But I added the output of `hadoop classpath --glob` to my system CLASSPATH var (Mint Linux 18.1 ) and nothing changed.

Hadoop ver : 2.7.3

my c code :

```
    hdfsFS fs = hdfsConnect("default",9000);
const char * writePath = "/test.txt";
hdfsFile writeFile = hdfsOpenFile(fs,writePath,0,sizeof(writePath),1,1024);
    if(!writeFile){
        printf("Error Opening HDFS File");
        exit(0);
    }
    const char * buffer= "Test ---- &^^$#@s";
    tSize num_written_bytes = hdfsWrite(fs, writeFile, (void*)buffer, strlen(buffer)+1);
    if (hdfsFlush(fs, writeFile)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to 'flush' %s\n", writePath);
        exit(-1);
    }
    hdfsCloseFile(fs, writeFile);
```

System CLASSPATH var :

```
/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-auth-2.7.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpcore-4.2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar
```

Comment: Why is this tagged C++ and C?  Why not Java since it is a Java exception you're dealing with?

Comment: because i use the C driver that uses jni

Comment: The problem isn't in the C driver; the problem is in the way the Java code can't find the C driver.  And that's a Java problem rather than a C problem.  Skills in C are not going to solve this; skills in Java and Java deployment may help.  The C language tag is, IMO, not appropriate.  You aren't about to show the source of the C driver, are you?

Answer (score 0):

`ExceptionUtils` is in the jar `commons-lang` and `commons-lang3`. Try adding either of those dependencies to your classpath:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.5</version>
</dependency>
```

[API Documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.5/org/apache/commons/lang3/exception/ExceptionUtils.html#getStackTrace-java.lang.Throwable-)